# Activate TinyMCE on displayForm() method Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, module, prestashop

My question seems very simple, but I did not find anything on the side of the documentation or during my research (at least that answers concerning 1.6) How to activate tinymce for the textarea of ​​my displayForm () method?

```php
'input' => array(
                        /* ... */

                          array(
                              'type' => 'textarea',
                              'label' => $this->l('Item Details'),
                              'required' => true,
                               // I tried this, indicated by the doc
                              'options' => array(
                                  'autoload' => true,
                                  'limit' => 21000
                              ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "AdminPatternsController" as a guide.

```
            array(
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'label' => 'text area with rich text editor',
                'name' => 'type_textarea_rte',
                'autoload_rte' => true
            ),
```